# ERROR Android Studio Emuator was killed and DxDiag Opens

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

**I cannot run Android Studio Emulator**, every time I was trying to run an AVD it will display an alert that **the emulator process was killed, afterwards DxDiag will automatically launch**.

I am currenly using **Android Studio version 4.1.1**. The skin of the emulator would not show and only the message that its process was killed. After a few minutes, DxDiag will automatically open. While DxDiag loads, my laptop would become very slow. When the DxDiag is opened, it will display a message similar to "Direct3D was used last time, would you like to bypass it?"

Please note that the emulator runs perfectly when I first installed Android Studio on my newly reformatted laptop. I don't what has had happened but it won't run again. I already did clean uninstallation, then reinstalled Android Studio with the version 4.1.1 since I thought that reinstalling and updating it would solve the problem, but it didn't. Sometimes the emulator would still run, but that was a very rare occasion and when I tried to rerun it again, it won't.

My laptop is Dell and I am using Windows 10.

**Here are my laptop's specifications:**

- System Type: x64
- System Model: Dell Inspiron 5567
- **Processor:** Intel Core i7-7500U CPU @ 2.70ghz
- **RAM:** 8gb
- **Display Graphics:** Intel Graphics
- **Render:** AMD Radeon Graphics
- **HDD:** 1TB

---

**Solutions that I have tried:**

- Updating Windows 10
- Scanning for Viruses
- Clean uninstallation of previous version of Android Studio then clean installation with the latest version
- Updating to the latest Android Emulator
- Reinstalling Intel HAXM
- Unchecking Launch in a Tool Window
- Disabling Quick Boot on AVD
- Choosing Software - GLES 2.0 in the Graphics of my AVD